# Disassembling strings from Inno Setup [Code]

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When I compile a Inno Setup project, the `[Code]` section is also compiled (as Pascal executable or Pascal DLL)?

In other words, if someone unpacks a Inno Setup project, can he see the `[Code]` section as original source code (damn! :) ) or as compiled executable/DLL (difficult to disassemble)?

I would like to insert in the `[Code]` section some strings (password and keys) and I don't know if they would be easily recoverable also with little knowledge of reverse engineering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is compiled into some kind of a binary representation (very roughly like [.NET CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) or [Java bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode)).

There's [Inno Setup Unpacker](https://innounp.sourceforge.net/) (and others like [innoextract](https://github.com/dscharrer/innoextract)), which can extract the files from `.exe` generated by Inno Setup. It can extract the binary representation of the code to `CompiledCode.bin` (if you use `-x -m` flags).

<del>Then you can use Inno Setup Decompiler project that is able to decompile/disassemble the `CompiledCode.bin` file into (pseudo) Pascal Script code. But as with a reverse engineering of .NET or Java, it won't give you exact code. The decompiled code possibly won't even compile (at least it was so the last time I tried), but it is good enough to see, what the code does. They seem to have a paid version now, which may be better than the free one I've tried some time ago. *(The latest version of Inno Setup Decompiler can even directly extract code from `.exe`, but it was not updated to the latest version of Inno Setup [5.6.1] yet, so it did not work for me.)*</del>

(Inno Setup Decompiler site is gone, but it does not change anything about the fact that it is technically possible to decompile/disassemble the compiled code)

---

It is rather easy to see literal strings compiled in the code, even in the `CompiledCode.bin`.

For example these credentials:

```pascal
Username := 'secretusername';
Password := 'mysupersecretpassword';
```

can be seen like this in the `CompiledCode.bin` file:

[image]

Of course, you can [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) the strings somehow (at least hex-encode them). But as you are hopefully aware, **no matter what you do, once the (even compiled) code is on user's machine, there's really no way you can protect it absolutely.**

A simple support code to store the string literal hex-encoded:

```pascal
function CryptStringToBinary(
  sz: string; cch: LongWord; flags: LongWord; binary: AnsiString; 
  var size: LongWord; skip: LongWord; flagsused: LongWord): Integer;
  external 'CryptStringToBinaryW@crypt32.dll stdcall';

const
  CRYPT_STRING_HEX = $04;

function UnobfuscateString(S: string): string;
var
  Size: LongWord;
  Buffer: AnsiString;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Buffer, (Length(S) div 2) + 1);
  Len := Length(S);
  Size := Len div 2;
  if (CryptStringToBinary(S, Len, CRYPT_STRING_HEX, Buffer, Size, 0, 0) = 0) or
     (Size <> Length(S) div 2) then
  begin
    RaiseException('Error unobfuscating string');
  end;
  Result := Buffer;
end;

#define ObfuscateString(str S) \
  Local[0] = AddBackslash(GetEnv("TEMP")) + "ObfuscatedString.pas", \
  Local[1] = \
    "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command """ + \
    "$bytes = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes('" + S + "'); " + \
    "$s = '''' + (($bytes | foreach { $_.ToString('X2') }) -join '') + ''''; " + \
    "Set-Content -Path '" + Local[0] + "' -Value $s;" + \
    """", \
  Exec("powershell.exe", Local[1], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
  Local[2] = FileOpen(Local[0]), \
  Local[3] = FileRead(Local[2]), \
  FileClose(Local[2]), \
  DeleteFileNow(Local[0]), \
  "UnobfuscateString(" + Local[3] + ")"
```

*(The code was tested on [Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848). Though, it can work with ASCII passwords only.)*

With the help of the code above, you can write this (so you have the credentials easily editable in the source code):

```pascal
Username := {#ObfuscateString("secretusername")};
Password := {#ObfuscateString("mysupersecretpassword")};
```

But the code will be compiled as:

```pascal
Username := UnobfuscateString('736563726574757365726E616D65');
Password := UnobfuscateString('6D79737570657273656372657470617373776F7264');
```

You can verify that by adding this to the end of your `.iss` script and checking the generated `Preprocessed.iss` file.

```pascal
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

So despite the credentials being readable in the source code, they won't be stored literally to the compiled code:

[image]

But again, this is only an obfuscation. Anyone with decent programming skills will be able to unobfuscate (decrypt) the credentials.