# Unable to display foreign language in Inno Setup 'AppPublisher' directive

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to create an installer file. The version I am using is 5. When the installer is installed in the Windows operating system, the `AppPublisher` is not displayed in correctly. Here is the sample code I wrote:

```
[Setup]
AppId={{23ASEADS-AB2}
AppName=EmptyProgram
AppVersion=1
AppPublisher=नमस्ते
```

However, I see something like this `à¤¨à¤®à¤¸à¥à¤¤à¥‡` instead of `नमस्ते`. Is there any solution for this situation? I also tried to use Hex value like :

```
AppPublisher=#$92892e93894d924947
```

But it ended up printing the same value and not the converted value. I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest Unicode version and make sure your script file is encoded as UTF8-BOM.

Comment: @Andrew is correct. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/esIhK.png

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I used latest Inno Setup installer and encoded the .iss file with BOM by saving the file with notepad++. But due to some random characters at the beginning of file, it complains about undeclared directive 'AppId'.

Comment: But did you install Unicode version?

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrew has commented:

- Make sure you are using the latest [Unicode version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) of Inno Setup and;
- Make sure your script file is encoded as UTF-8 **with** BOM.