# Inno Setup event that is generated when folder is browsed on TInputDirWizardPage?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using a custom `TInputDirWizardPage` to input three different target folders for my installation.

When the first folder is changed, I'd like to automatically change the 3rd folder's path. Is it possible to create an event that occurs when the Browse button is used for the first folder and a specific folder is selected? If so, is it also possible to change the 3rd folder's path programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `TInputDirWizardPage.Buttons[0].OnClick` event handler:

```pascal
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  PrevFirstButtonClick: TNotifyEvent;

procedure FirstButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  PrevValue: string;
begin
  PrevValue := DirPage.Values[0];

  { Call remembered handler }
  PrevFirstButtonClick(Sender);

  if DirPage.Values[0] <> PrevValue then
  begin
    { And do whatever you want to do when the value changes }
    MsgBox(Format('Value changed from "%s" to "%s".', [PrevValue, DirPage.Values[0]]),
      mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardSelectDir), '', '', False, '');
  { add directory input page items }
  DirPage.Add('Path to Apache:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to PHP:');
  DirPage.Add('Path to Server Files:');

  { Remember the standard handler }
  PrevFirstButtonClick := DirPage.Buttons[0].OnClick;
  { And assign our override } 
  DirPage.Buttons[0].OnClick := @FirstButtonClick;
end;
```

The code needs Unicode version of Inno Setup. Calling `DirPage.Buttons[0].OnClick` strangely does not work in Ansi version.

Comment: If I set DirPage.Values[0] it'll change the contents of the edit box?

Comment: I've tried and this code doesn't work for me. Clicking the Browse button for the first button doesn't do any action.

Comment: It works, if I copy and paste the code to a blank .iss file.  If it does not work for you, you probably have some other code that conflicts with it. Please show us [mcve].

Comment: I've tried creating an empty iss file and it doesn't work for me. I'm using an older version of inno 5.5.3. I'll try to install a brand new copy on another computer and see if it works like that.

Comment: OK, I've found out that the code indeed does not work in Ansi version of Inno Setup. It looks like a bug. But you should be using Unicode version anyway.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for the help and for the sample code! it really worked!