# Why is installer compiled in Inno Setup 6 one MB larger than in Inno Setup 5

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

I have an Inno Setup script to make my application into an exe.

When I compile the code using Inno Setup version 6, the output file size is *110MB* (as shown in Windows Explorer size column)

But when I compile the same script in Inno Setup version 5, the output file size is *109MB* (1 MB smaller).

Why there is a difference in size? Is this a problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A compiled installer is actually an identical copy of `SetupLdr.e32` with a compressed copy of `Setup.e32` appended (along with actual installation files). Both these files are present in Inno Setup installation folder.

Those two files have:

- 0.68 + 2.41 MB in Inno Setup 6
- 0.11 + 1.13 MB in Inno Setup 5 Unicode
- 0.05 + 0.68 MB in Inno Setup 5 Ansi

---

From [Inno Setup 6.0 revision history](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.0-whatsnew.htm):

> Delphi compiler updated from Delphi 2009 to Delphi 10.3 Rio. This change increases the size of Setup but decreases development, testing and deployment times.

This is also indirectly relevant:

> Starting with Inno Setup 6 there's only one version available: Unicode Inno Setup.