# Inno Setup uninstall file size has increased dramatically

Tags: inno-setup

I upgraded to the latest version of Inno Setup recently and noticed that the size of the uninstall file is very large compared to what it was under the older version (I was previously using a version from a year or two ago - I don't have the exact older version information).

Is there a way to significantly reduce the size of the uninstall file?

My average setup file is now about twice as large as it used to be (and this is strictly due to the increased uninstall file size).

Comment: See [Why is installer compiled in Inno Setup 6 one MB larger than in Inno Setup 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57175708/850848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno Setup 6 is compiled with Delphi 10.3 Rio whilst older versions with Delphi 2009. Your only option is to compile your own Inno Setup from source either with the old Delphi version (if it's compilable), or use certain binary size reduction techniques for Delphi 10.3 Rio version (though there's a few already used, so I would not be much optimistic about a way to reduce the binary size more than it is).