# Show text with hyperlink on page InfoBeforeFile in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup for my application. I want to show a text with hyperlink in Inno Setup while installation. When user clicks that link it will navigate to particular URL.
I tried create text this hyperlink in RTF format, but Inno Setup ignore this and showed full link.

[image: I need it to look like that]

Comment: In my opinion, clickable hyperlinks for a setup program (particularly if it runs elevated) should be avoided because a compromised web server might lead to a security issue.

Comment: it helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158677/upgrading-from-ansi-to-unicode-version-of-inno-setup-any-disadvantages