# Int64 variable in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, int64

We use some Pascal Scripting in our Inno Setup 5.5.8 and in our `Code` section are some `Integer` variables. In this variable we store the actual date and time in this format: `YYMMDDhhmm`. Since the year `2022` the value is too big for an `Integer`. Is there a `Int64` in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Unicode* version of Inno Setup has `Int64`.

For example, see [`StrToInt64`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_strtoint64).

---

There's only the *Unicode* version in recent versions of Inno Setup. Though 5.5.8 still had Ansi version too. We do not know what version you are using, but I guess the Ansi one, otherwise you won't be asking. You should be [using the Unicode version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) in any case. `Int64` was introduced in [Inno Setup 5.5.3](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.5.3). *Btw, Inno Setup 5.5.8 is 6 years old. Do not use it.*

---

Imo, storing timestamp as an integer in `YYMMDDhhmm` format is not a good idea. Why don't you use a `string`?